# hide() method of jquery not working after clicking a button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two buttons where one button i.e `Staffing` and another button i.e `NonStaffing`. When I click on the `Staffing` button then I'm able to get my desired result, meaning I'm able to see page1 and hide page2. But when I click on the `NonStaffing` button then I'm not getting my desired result, meaning hiding page1 and showing page2. It hides the whole page. I'm not able to figure out the problem.

HTML:

```
<ul>
     <li class="menu-item" style="list-style-type: none;margin-left: 50px; margin-top: -120px; position: absolute;">
        <input   type="submit" name="projectType" value="Staffing" >
     </li>
    <li style="list-style-type: none;margin-left: 150px; margin-top: -120px; position: absolute;" >
        <input type="submit" name="projectType1" value="NonStaffing">
    </li>
</ul>


<div id="abc1" style="background: #CCC; height:250px;width:250px;margin-top:150px;border: 4px solid #AAA;">
   <button>Open Dialog</button>
        Page1  

</div>


<div id ="mno" style="background: #CCC; height:110px;width:150px;margin-left:410px;margin-top: -250px; border: 4px solid #AAA;"> Page2

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var dialogOffset = {
    top: 50,
    left: 10
}
  $("input:submit[name=projectType1]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value=='NonStaffing'){

        $('#mno').show();
         $('#abc1').hide();


    }else{


    }
});



     $("input:submit[name=projectType]").click(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                    if(value=='Staffing'){
                        $('#abc1').show();
                        $('#mno').hide();
                    }else{}
                }); 



$('button').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('div.col');
    var parentPos = $parent.offset()
    var parentIndex = $('.col').index($parent);   
    var numDialogs= $('.colDialog_'+parentIndex).length;
    var dialogTop=parentPos.top + dialogOffset.top + numDialogs*30;
    var dialogPosition = [parentPos.left + dialogOffset.left, dialogTop];
    $('<div class="colDialog_'+parentIndex+'">').dialog({      
        position:  dialogPosition,
        width: 170,
        title: 'Col:'+(parentIndex+1 +', Dia: '+(numDialogs+1)) ,
        close: function() {
            $(this).remove()
        }
    })
});​
```

And you can find a JSFiddle of the code above [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CPtp4/4/).

Comment: What happens is that all the elements are out of view when the only element with a positive margin is hidden. Is there a good reason for this positioning strategy?

Comment: Your code is quite difficult to understand : try to reduce the use of css (absolute position and negative margin are generally a bad practice). Simplify all that stuff and you will see that it will solve your bug (which is in fact a css problem due to negative margin)

Comment: actually i was not aware of that negative margin can drag me to these problems .Anyways i learnt a new thing today though i'm new to IT industry . Thanx alot :)

Comment: @Anuj Next time please include your code here. Don't just add a JSFiddle link. Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" class="chgpage" rel="abc1" value="Staffing" >
<input type="submit" class="chgpage" rel="mno" value="NonStaffing">
<div id="abc1" class="page" style="display:none;width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid black;">Page1</div>
<div id ="mno" class="page" style="display:none;width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid red;">Page2</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
     $("input.chgpage").click(function() {
         $('div.page').hide();
         $('#'+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
</script>
```

Have Fun ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified code : it is not perfect but I've tried to keep the philosophy of your code. It fixes the problem which was caused by a bad use of negative margin and absolute positioning. The javascript can be the same...

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none; margin-top: 50px;">
     <li class="menu-item" style="margin-left: 50px; display: inline-block;">
        <input   type="submit" name="projectType" value="Staffing" >
     </li>
    <li style="margin-left: 50px; display: inline-block;" >
        <input type="submit" name="projectType1" value="NonStaffing">
    </li>
</ul>

<div style="margin-top:150px; position: relative;">
    <div id="abc1" style="position: absolute; background: #CCC; height:250px; width:250px; border: 4px solid #AAA;">
       <button>Open Dialog</button>
            Page1         
    </div>


    <div id ="mno" style="position: absolute; left: 350px; background: #CCC; height:110px; width:150px; border: 4px solid #AAA;"> Page2

    </div>
</div>
```

​

Comment: Thanx all .Its woking for me . But i have more question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410646/dialog-box-remains-open-after-redirect-to-another-page